# a split preg_match or something else

Tags: php, preg-match

Can someone please examine this bit of code. I am aware that i could use `/i` to make this case insensitive. But, even though I am not, I'm still getting visitors who definitely have $user_agent set, but slip through this and I cant firgure out why.

```
<?php
$user = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match("/android|linux|windows|Android|Linux|Windows/",$user))  {
header("Refresh:0;url=http://site.com/page.php/");
};
?>

<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(preg_match("/term-one|term-two|term-three/",$referrer))  {
header("Refresh:0;url=http://site.com/page.php/");
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: If things are getting past your regexp that should be caught, why not add some logging to the end to echo out what their User Agent or Referer is?

Comment: Dumb question, but if you are sure they have the USER_AGENT set, are you also sure that the value contains one of your 3 matches

Comment: It's easy to spoof the user agent, maybe that's the reason that some users slip through ?

Comment: Well google analytics is showing USER_AGENT info as, for example, Chrome / Windows and Safari / Windows. But those and more with "Windows" still get by the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `exit;` statement after your first `header()` call.
If it will often still appear to work, but your code will continue to execute and if something later in our code re-sets the `Refresh` header, the first redirect will never happen.

Also, since refresh happens after the page finishes loading and you the missing `exit` means you continue to load the contents - including, presumably, the google analytics code, then even if they do eventually refresh away to the right page, they'll still be recorded by google analytics as having loaded this page first.

Incidently, why are you using the `Refresh` header instead of the `Location` header for redirects?

My recommended code would be:

```
<?php
    $user = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (preg_match("/android|linux|windows/i", $user)) {
        header("Location: http://site.com/page.php");
        exit;
    }
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (preg_match("/term-one|term-two|term-three/", $referrer))  {
        header("Location: http://site.com/page.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```